# Airflow with varying conda environments

Tags: airflow

I have an ecosystem where I have multiple git repositories. Each repository has its own conda environment that is very specific to that repo and `does stuff`.

In investigating airflow, it appears to be a great fit for problems I face.

My stack is likely familiar to a lot of airflow users, namely:

- **the [environment required for airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) is not a one-size-fits-all for all the code I need to run**

I am curious to know how people deal with this in the wild.

Do most [DAGs][2] call [bash operators][3] vs [python operators][4]?

Is the idealized vision for airflow that all `python operator` tasks are actually calling web services via [requests][5] or something similarly abstracted?

I am definitely planning on using airflow to solve some messy problems but want to be sure I build in the right direction and did not find a clearly organized doc on this exact question.

It would seem 100% suboptimal, and not in the vision of the project, to install airflow in each environment and have each airflow instance own various tasks (this may even cause airflow issues I am unfamiliar with). If I am wrong on this point, I should course-correct immediately.

Thank you to anyone in the community who can provide guidance on this.

[2]: [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/concepts.html#:~:text=In%20Airflow%2C%20a%20DAG%20%E2%80%93%20or,and%20their%20dependencies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/concepts.html#:%7E:text=In%20Airflow%2C%20a%20DAG%20%E2%80%93%20or,and%20their%20dependencies))%20as%20code.
[3]: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html
[4]: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html
[5]: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

For your case you can use:

- PythonVirtualeEnvOperator - this one will build new virtualenv every time it needs one so might be a little brittle
- KubernetesPodOperator - where you can have different variant of the images with different environments and choose the one you want for each task (requires Kubernetes)
- DockerOperator - same as KubernetesPodOperator, but requires just Docker engine

However the best thing for that is availale as of Airflow 2.2.

In the new Airflow 2.2 (released literally few days ago) you also have the new `@task.docker` decorator which allows you to combine the best of both worlds:

1. separate images to keep your envs isolated and manageable
2. Python code which is written as regular decorated function in your DAG.

More info here:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html#using-the-taskflow-api-with-docker-or-virtual-environments

Comment: Is there a strong reason not to use `BashOperator`?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer points in the right direction, but it's not answering the question of using conda env in AirFlow.

I think it is achievable by using `@task.external_python`, though I haven't tested it yet:

```py
@task.external_python(task_id="external_python", python=PATH_TO_PYTHON_BINARY_FROM_CONDA)
    def callable_external_python():
        # do your staff
```

Docs:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#using-python-environment-with-pre-installed-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- Each environment is standalone as it relates to the project, repo or however your ecosystem natively works. For me its something like:

  ~/path_to_env1/python ~/dostuff1.py

  ~/path_to_env2/python ~/dostuff2.py
- Wrap that call in a bash job. My jobs live in the repo for the project.
- Use `bashoperator` and simply point to that `~/repo1/jobs/thing.sh`  (please note that this trailing space is required given an airflow bug.

You could also skip my bash job step and put the call directly into airflow. For me, I chose to put the wrapper of the job to provide a concept more like a view to "do stuff" related to a project or workflow rather than run one script.

This is fully a design choice and up for debate.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar problem. Most of the time it is ok to call the python interpreter with the full path, but sometimes it isn't.

Please take a look at https://github.com/lynker-analytics/airflow-conda-operator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.